# two rows of two buttons in html on right side without disrupting the left side

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a menu consisting of four buttons on my webpage and I want two buttons on the top and two buttons on the bottom.  I have the following CSS code:

```
.navButton {
padding: 3%;
float:right;
background:#C0C0C0;
margin-left:1%;
margin-right:1%;
}
```

and then used br to make the second two go down but then it disrupted everything on the left side of the page.  How can I make 4 equally sized buttons sit evenly in the top right corner.  Right now because the words are slightly different sizes the buttons are a little different and I would love for the them to be exactly equal.

Thanks!

Comment: can you create an example in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: why not just set font-size for them if its showing the way you like now

Comment: here is a link to an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/CYjqS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://shaquin.tk/experiments/menu2.html).

I just made it.

Just view the source and copy the HTML+CSS.

Comment: okay that's great! now my top right button is actually an image is there anyway i can make all the buttons square a about twice as large?

Comment: @clifgray: Done now - http://jsfiddle.net/pefGx/. Do you want it any smaller/larger?

Comment: I changed it a little bit to make it larger but thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

try this after two a tags enter

```
<div style="clear:right"></div>
```

and remove br tags.

Comment: that does the trick for aligning them but still leaves the title down below it all

Answer (score 0):

After the two a tags insert this:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on this question? giving a couple of code lines can lead to misunderstanding. tnx